# BufferedInputStream is throwing out-of-memory errors in Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, out-of-memory

I'm trying to use a `BufferedInputStream` to load an external DICOM file, but it eventually runs out of memory. When I used an `InputStream`, this never came up (I did this when I was loading the file through the `assets` folder).

I created my own producer-consumer threads to buffer the file, so I don't actually need the BufferedInputStream, but I DO need to use `mark()` and `reset()` which is not available in `FileInputStream`.

How should I go around this? Is there another kind of `InputStream` that I can use with a `File` which has the `mark()`/`reset()` functions? Can I empty the buffer somehow before the `BufferedInputStream` throws the error? Or should I find a way around using `mark()` instead?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: how big of a buffer are you using?

Comment: I'm using the default value (I believe that's 8024 or so). I can't create a buffer that's the size of the file because it's too big, so I have to read it in chunks.

Comment: is it possible that the chunks are too big?  Have you tried smaller buffer sizes?

Comment: Hmm, not yet. I'll try and get back to you on that. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I tried using 4096 and 1024 buffer sizes, but both still throw oom errors. From what I can tell, it's crashing after the same number of reads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `mark` and `reset` to work with buffered input the file points between the `mark` and `reset` need to remain in memory.

Workarounds depend on what you're actually trying to do; if you just need to start reading from a known location, perhaps a `RandomAccessFile`.